# Turn `ReloadOnChange` off in config source for WebApplicationFactory

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, bitbucket-pipelines

This is both a question and an answer. I've fixed my problem, but it seems a bit wrong.

My original problem is running my asp.net core integration tests in a bitbucket pipeline causes  `System.IO.IOException: The configured user limit (128) on the number of inotify instances has been reached.` Some solutions call for changing some setting through `sysctl`, but that is [restricted by bitbucket](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/run-docker-commands-in-bitbucket-pipelines-879254331.html#RunDockercommandsinBitbucketPipelines-RunningDockercommands), so that isn't an option for me.

The second way of fixing this, as noted in [these stackoverflow answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45875981/error-while-reading-json-file-in-dotnet-core-the-configured-user-limit-128-on), is to turn `reloadOnChange` off.

My new problem is now, how do we *best* do this for the test `WebApplicationFactory`?

One solution that has worked for me, which is the least amount of code, seems like a total hack. I iterate through all the `JsonConfigurationSource` and set `ReloadOnChange` to `false`.

Full solution:

```
public class TestApplicationFactory : WebApplicationFactory<Startup>
{
    protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.ConfigureAppConfiguration(config =>
        {
            foreach (var source in config.Sources)
            {
                if (source is JsonConfigurationSource)
                {
                    var jsonConfigSource = (JsonConfigurationSource) source;
                    jsonConfigSource.ReloadOnChange = false;
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Another solution, that I haven't tried, may be to [override `CreateWebHostBuilder()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.testing.webapplicationfactory-1.createwebhostbuilder?view=aspnetcore-3.0#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_Testing_WebApplicationFactory_1_CreateWebHostBuilder). However, it seems like more code and a lot of copy and paste from the [default one](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/v2.2.8/src/DefaultBuilder/src/WebHost.cs).

Am I missing something? Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Just experienced this issue myself running integration tests within a Linux container and followed the previous suggestions to switch off the ReloadOnChange within the WebApplicationFactory.  Unfortunately that did not resolve the problem and integration tests were still failing with the same error:

```
System.IO.IOException: The configured user limit (128) on the number of inotify instances has been reached.
```

I also tried to configure xUnit to run the integration tests sequentially rather than in parallel, but that did not work either.

The solution that did work for me was to set the appropriate environment variable within the container that runs the integration tests:

```
export ASPNETCORE_hostBuilder__reloadConfigOnChange=false
```

Comment: that is good to know will give it a try

Comment: This is also possible via an appconfig.json change, for .NET 5.0+

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/generic-host?view=aspnetcore-5.0#disable-app-configuration-reload-on-change

Comment: You guys just saved my day. Thank you for this. Note, I needed to use the prefix DOTNET_ as mentioned by @sroll

Answer (score 3):

I just encountered the same issue.

Setting the env variable `DOTNET_hostBuilder:reloadConfigOnChange` to `false` fixed it.

This solution works for net6 when you use the Generic Host. For other hosts, maybe try replacing `DOTNET_` prefix with `ASPNETCORE_`

To make it simple, I set it in my code before creating the WebApplicationFactory

```
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("DOTNET_hostBuilder:reloadConfigOnChange", "false");
```

Comment: Thanks for answering... although it may be for a different dotnet version, it seems like Ben's answer is similar to this already: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69433780/2088345. I never got around to trying it though.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without inheriting from WebApplicationFactory by using the `WithWebHostBuilder` and `ConfigureAppConfiguration` extension methods:

```
var webAppFactory = new WebApplicationFactory<Startup>().WithWebHostBuilder(webHostBuilder =>
{
    webHostBuilder.ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, configBuilder) =>
        configBuilder.Sources.Where(s => s is FileConfigurationSource).ToList()
            .ForEach(s => ((FileConfigurationSource)s).ReloadOnChange = false));
});
```

This accomplishes the same thing as your original idea (which helped me a lot!), but more compact and without the need for a separate class definition.

Comment: Glad it helped you a lot. Thanks for your suggestion. I used a class because I reuse the `TestApplicationFactory` in multiple places and did not want to duplicate the code.

Comment: What's super strange is I run into this trying to do a Java function app. It's like Java function apps use DOTNET under the hood. `docker run -e DOTNET_hostBuilder:reloadConfigOnChange=false -p 8080:80 -it foo:0.0.1` did not fix the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

`builder.ConfigureAppConfiguration` is there to configure your (main) application.

You can use `builder.ConfigureHostConfiguration` (see [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#configure-the-host-builder-with-configurehostconfiguration)) to explicitly configure files to be read for the **host**.

```
builder.ConfigureHostConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
{
    config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: false);
});
```

The host configuration is loaded. ASP.NET Core from 3.0 is built based on Generic host (rather than the Web Host of the former versions).

Comment: You're saying this only applies to ASP.NET Core 3.0? I'm on 2.2 and I didn't see `ConfigureHostConfiguration` in the docs for 2.2.

Comment: As stated, generic host is used as default host mechanism for ASP.NET Core 3.0. Before that, WebHost (`WebHostBuilder` class) was used to bootstrap an ASP.NET Core application. WebHostBuilder also (still) works in .NET Core 3.0 (i.e. if you migrated), but new applications created via the tempate use ` Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(...)` / `HostBuilder` class

Comment: thanks, so the answer would work if I migrated to 3.0? Do you know of a way of doing something similar in 2.2? I could clarify in my question the stack I'm using