# What's missing from our custom Linux OS that causes "Function not implemented" when building the Grapevine web server?

Tags: linux, grapevine

We are seeing the following trace when attempting to run Grapevine on a custom Linux OS (we don't see this running on Ubuntu 20.04 or Raspberry Pi):

```
WARNING: System.IO.IOException: Function not implemented
at System.IO.FileSystemWatcher.StartRaisingEvents()
at System.IO.FileSystemWatcher.StartRaisingEventsIfNotDisposed()
at System.IO.FileSystemWatcher.set_EnableRaisingEvents(Boolean value)
at Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Physical.PhysicalFilesWatcher.TryEnableFileSystemWatcher()
at Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Physical.PhysicalFilesWatcher.CreateFileChangeToken(String filter)
at Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.PhysicalFileProvider.Watch(String filter)
at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileConfigurationProvider.<.ctor>b__1_0()
at Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.ChangeToken.ChangeTokenRegistration`1..ctor(Func`1 changeTokenProducer, Action`1 changeTokenConsumer, TState state)
at Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.ChangeToken.OnChange(Func`1 changeTokenProducer, Action changeTokenConsumer)
at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileConfigurationProvider..ctor(FileConfigurationSource source)
at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json.JsonConfigurationProvider..ctor(JsonConfigurationSource source)
at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json.JsonConfigurationSource.Build(IConfigurationBuilder builder)
at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilder.Build()
```

Clearly we're missing something in our custom OS that dotnet (and Grapevine) depends upon. Can anyone provide a clue on what that might be?

We tried turning off 'Reload on change' per this link:

([Turn `ReloadOnChange` off in config source for WebApplicationFactory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60295562/turn-reloadonchange-off-in-config-source-for-webapplicationfactory/69433780#69433780))

That didn't do anything for us. By the way, turning off the file system watcher so this exception isn't raised would be an acceptable work-around.

Comment: We did find this: https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/2330#issuecomment-1402418691 - perhaps Microsoft didn't implement the function for ARM64?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We've found what's missing in our custom Linux! In case you're encountering this issue, make sure you've built "inotify" functionality into your kernel. [Inotify Man Page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html)